# How to Intersect multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, intersect

I have set up a php page so there are multiple options for data input that gets put into multiple temporary tables, each one separated with querying the database based on 1 condition given in the data input. So if the input is age > 10 and shoesize > 6 and height > 60, there will be three temporary tables table0, table1, and table2 where table0 is only data age > 10 and table1 is only data shoesize > 6 and table 2 is only data height > 60.

I am wondering how to intersect these so I will only get the results that have all requirements met with age > 10 and shoesize > 6 and height > 60. My attempt using the "WHERE EXISTS" clause is below but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM table0 t0
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM table1 t1
     WHERE EXISTS
         (SELECT *
          FROM table2 t2
          WHERE t0.age = t1.age = t2.age
            AND t0.shoesize = t1.shoesize = t2.shoesize
            AND t0.height = t1.height = t2.height));
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data ?

Comment: data consists of 6 columns age, gender, shoesize, weight, height, eyes. It is stored in one table in the database, and the temporary tables are just subsets of the original table, each with 1 condition applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that queries like this without relying on a table's primary key become cumbersome, so I'd recommend you add a primary key.

That said, the query you need is quite close to what you had already attempted:

```
SELECT *
FROM table0 t0
WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM table1 t1
          WHERE t1.age = t0.age AND t1.gender = t0.gender
            AND t1.shoesize = t0.shoesize AND t1.weight = t0.weight
            AND t1.height = t0.height AND t1.eyes = t0.eyes) AND
      EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM table2 t2
          WHERE t2.age = t0.age AND t2.gender = t0.gender
            AND t2.shoesize = t0.shoesize AND t2.weight = t0.weight
            AND t2.height = t0.height AND t2.eyes = t0.eyes)
```

***Note***: The query above will work only if none of the values is NULL.

Comment: This doesn't work :/ I get an error that the query has improper syntax (i.e. fetch_array on non-object)

Comment: @Steven the query does not include any fetch_array, how could it fail due to that?

Comment: I use the query in a mysqli query statement and then fetch_array to get the result, which fails when the query statement is invalid.

Comment: I have also confirmed it by repeating the temporary table process directly in sql and trying this query.

Comment: @Steven Can you produce the error message you get when running this query exactly as it is here?

Comment: ah ok so I just read through the version of this in the mysqli->query statement and I say an extra " ) " that did not belong. That is why there was an error. now the mysqli and the direct sql query are the same in that they pull up no results which I assumed before was it not working, but now I realize that the query is correct in syntax but just not correctly identifying specific intersecting results. I inserted 10 results that all met the criteria "age > 10 and shoesize > 6 and height > 60" and but none result after the query.

Comment: @Steven Are there any NULL values in any of the tables?

Comment: nope all values are either float or string depending on the field and are filled in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108602/discussion-between-ziggy-crueltyfree-zeitgeister-and-steven).